# Covariant derivative for of a scalar

Tags: differential-geometry

Can someone expands the identity mention in given image e.g. the double-double covariant derivative of an arbitrary scalar?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could show the image? Or explain what it is that you are seeking?

Comment: Hint: work from the left to the right, not the other way around.